# a lot of template (.tpl.php) files, is it good or not?

Tags: theming, files

I have used about 110 template files (tpl.php) in my theme, will that slow my drupal site?

I mean:

> more template files == consume Server performance.

Comment: Having a lot of files by itself is not necessarily a problem.  If you're concerned, try benchmarking your site with a theme that uses the template files and then another theme that does not.

Comment: From your comment I understand that a lot of template files will not consume Server performance, is that right ?.
 If I try benchmarking I will not see the difference because Im working in Localhost. so you have any idea

Comment: localhost or remote host you need server to run PHP, and most of the bench-marking in world are done in local environment. Benchmark gives results, and those numbers can show you difference.

Comment: Im sorry Jhilke Dai, I dont get it !! is Benchmark software or what, Im sorry Im jsut a Beginner.

Comment: Patrick means to say try to test your current site with current theme and benchmark it with Other themes, for example `Bartik`. If your benchmark shows difference in performance then your theme is slowing the site.

Comment: What do you mean with "your benchmark", what is benchmark, and how to work with it !!

Comment: `Benchmark` means compare more than one things and see the similarities/Differences. I mean you to Check the Server performance of your site with your current theme . Next, enable `Bartik` theme and check the Server Performance of your site with `Bartik` theme. If Bartik's Performance is better than your current theme, your current theme is making your site slow with too many `.tpl.php`

Comment: I know all that, its logic !! . Im asking for how to Check the server performance ? as I said before Im working in LOCALHOST, so I dont have cPanel or something like that to check performance. PS: Thanx for your time ;)

Comment: `Apache Bench`, `http-perf` are few famous ones. Just Google **Server Performance Benchmark Tool** you'll see lots of them both free and commercials. Chose what suits your best. I personally like `http-perf` and `Jmeter`

Comment: OK Jhulke Dai, Thanx for All those information. you really help me, Thanx again

Comment: On properly configured server it'll be served from opcode cache anyway, so the number of files have literally no impact on performance, only the raw amount of code that needs to be executed (and it's cost) matters. One file, 110 files, one opcode entry either way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Say you override the default page.tpl.php with your own in your theme folder, and compare this to the case of using the default. In both cases, **one** page.tpl.php is being evaluated during the page render process - either the default template or yours. Even if you do not override the template, Drupal must search the theme folder to check if an override exists. Of course, if you have a lot of complex logic in your override the page will render more slowly, but that is not due to the overriding itself.

Creating custom templates with hook_theme might slow things down, though.

In general, caching will do more to speed up your site since it bypasses page rendering altogether.

Comment: Thanx user24505 for the Answer

Comment: If you are replacing a theme function with call to template file, it will certainly slow down (at least relatively) because function calls are faster than file operations.